# How many ways you can distribute 8 distinct items in 2 different boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

Given that there are $8$ items $m, n, p, q, r, s, t,$ and $u$ will be distributed in box X and box Y, answer the following questions:

a.  How many ways can you distribute the given items if either Box $X$ or Box $Y$ can have no item?

This is how I answered this problem.

Consider the equation $X + Y = 8$ where $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative integers from $0$ to $8$. We're looking for the number of solutions this equation has. Thus, we can use the start and bars method.

In this case, the total number of ways is $_9C_1$.

But accoding to my partner, the answer must $2^8$.

b.  How many ways you can distribute the given items such that there must be at least $1$ item in both Box $X$ and Box $Y$?

In this case, I expressed $X$ as $X' + 1$ and $Y$ as $Y'+ 1$

Hence, $X'+1 + Y'+1 = 8$.
$X'+Y' = 6$
This follows that the number of ways to distribute is $_7C_1$.

But the answer of my partner is $2^8-2$ ways.

I am a bit confused on our answers.
Any comments or suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the number of solutions to $X+Y=8$ does not  take into account that they are distinct items. For example, having 3 items in X and 5 items in Y does not count one configuration because $X = \{m,n,p\}, Y = \{q,r,s,t,u\}$ is a different configuration you need to count separately from $X = \{q,n,p\}, Y = \{m,r,s,t,u\}$ (switched $q$ and $m$)

Answer (score 2):

a) $2^8$ is correct. Note that we have $2$ choices for a box, and we have to make this choice $8$ times.

b) From part a), we know that there are $2^8$ ways to distribute $8$ unique items among $2$ unique boxes. We see the word “at least”; this implies that we may be able to use complementary counting. That is, $$\text{The number of ways at least one item is in both boxes } = \text{ The number of ways we can place distribute the items without restrictions } - \text{The number of ways a box has all of the items}.$$ This is a common technique used in counting. We see that the number of ways we can have each box have all $8$ items is $2$, since either box $X$ or box $Y$ has it. Indeed, $2^8 - 2$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in star and bar method, all stars are alike. For your question, take a case where you put $7$ items in box A and $1$ item in box B. It matters which is that one item in box $B$. There are $8$ ways to do just that whereas star and bar method will count it as $1$.

So the way you have to look at is that you have two independent (box) choices for each item and so for two distinguisable items $2^2$ choices and so on...

In part ($b$), minus $2$ is to take out $2$ cases where one of the boxes is empty - there are only two cases - when all items get into either box $A$ or box $B$.